# Sum previous purchase records

Tags: mysql

I want to create a report to know if someone is a new buyer or a returning buyer. My table is looking like this.

```
Order Date          | Name |  Qty
2019-11-11 18:27:14   Tia      1
2019-12-09 14:13:51   Tia      1
2019-12-14 20:42:29   Tia      2
2020-01-14 18:13:00   Tia      1
```

I want to describe her as a returning buyer start from 2nd row because she already purchased something in the past. I need my table to be like this.

```
Order Date          | Name | Qty | Total Qty | Buyer Type
2019-11-11 18:27:14   Tia      1        1         New Buyer
2019-12-09 14:13:51   Tia      1        2       Returning Buyer
2019-12-14 20:42:29   Tia      2        4       Returning Buyer
2020-01-14 18:13:00   Tia      1        5       Returning Buyer
```

How to sum her previous order? I already try using CASE and COUNT but it didn't come out as I want.

```
SELECT
    create_time AS 'Order Date'
    , member_name AS 'Name'
    , COUNT(code) AS 'Qty'
    , CASE
        WHEN COUNT(code) > 1 THEN 'Returning buyer'
        ELSE 'New buyer'
    END AS 'BUYER TYPE'
FROM
    db_bb_mall_trade1_prod.t_so_salesorder
GROUP BY
    date(create_time), member_id;
```

Comment: What is MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina I'm using MySQL version 5.6.16

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a tedious choice as a table/column identifier

Comment: (I feel like I may have mentioned some of this stuff before)

Comment: @Strawberry I'm sorry, I always forgot that order is a reserved word. I'll edit the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.order_date, t1.name, t1.order,  
       SUM(t2.order) total_order,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.order_date) = 1
            THEN 'New Buyer'
            ELSE 'Returning Buyer'
            END buyer_type
FROM src_table t1
JOIN src_table t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
                 AND t1.order_date >= t2.order_date
GROUP BY t1.order_date, t1.name, t1.order
```

Comment: Total order column is missing, which is where the main issue is as we don't have window function in mysql 5.6

Comment: @Gosfly No problems, it can be fixed easily.

Comment: This is brillant ! +1